# error: method must be a string , Alexa custom skill

Tags: node.js, nodes, alexa-skills-kit

while consuming REST API POST request using nodejs in Alexa custom skill using "Alexa Skill Kit" (AWS Lambda nodejs environment) .
this is my code inside index.js

```
   'use strict';
   const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
   const request = require('sync-request');

   'validateClientIntent': function() {
          var json = {
            "clientID": "xxxxx6EF-9D05-49CE-855C-C41CED4A83B5",
            "appKey": "D/xxxxxxxxisFSMMzAbntGsrNf0yX6aafNqoyi8="
        };
        var options = {
        url: 'http://link',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: json
        };
        //var method = "POST";
        //options = JSON.parse(options);
        try {
            request(options, function(err, res, body) {
                if (res && (res.statusCode === 200 || res.statusCode === 
        201)) {
                    //var body = JSON.parse(body);
                    var trackingId = body;
                    //console.log(trackingId);
                    //return trackingId;
                    this.response.speak(trackingId);
                }
                else {
                    throw (err);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.response.speak(err);

        }
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
```

Comment: Without knowing what your actual problem is, I don't know why you are using "sync-request", as it even says on their readme to not use them. Use something like "request-promise" or "axios" and wait for their promises to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

in this I am using 'sync-request', so use the below method as provided in 
'https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request'

```
var request = require('sync-request');

var res = request('POST', 'https://example.com/create-user', {
   json: {username: 'ForbesLindesay'},
});

var user = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));
```